# Conditionally adding custom content on WooCommerce custom product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

Morning All,

I have created a snippet of code that pulls the relevant information from a post image and shows 3 options for download.

I've changed the design of the site to run on Products from Woocommerece, how can i tweak my code snippet to allow this feature to work?

```
<?php if(in_category(531)) { ?>
                <?php if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) { ?>
                <p>
                &darr; Download Image<br />
                <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'web', true);
                echo $image_url[0]; ?>" ><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForWeb.png" alt="download for web" /></a><br />

                <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'print', true);
                echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForPrint.png" alt="download for print" /></a><br />

                <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'', true);
                echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForProPrint.png" alt="download for pro print" /></a><br />
                </p>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <h2>Special permission required</h2>
                <p>In order to use this image you need special permission from the admin, please fill in the form below and we'll get back to
                you as soon as possible...</p>
                <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form 11 "special permission"]' ) ?>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                <p>
                &darr; Download Image<br />
                <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'web', true);
                echo $image_url[0]; ?>" ><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForWeb.png" alt="download for web" /></a><br />

                <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'print', true);
                echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForPrint.png" alt="download for print" /></a><br />

                <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'', true);
                echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForProPrint.png" alt="download for pro print" /></a><br />
                </p>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Here is a link, i'd like it displayed under Keywords.
http://www.redrocketgraphicdesign.co.uk/test/FIRST/product/firststudent1/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec This is a single product page. When this was set-up as a post, it worked like this https://snag.gy/jCDgqK.jpg

You click your desired option and it downloads the relevant image, the code above is how it worked as a post. i'd like to switch this to work on the product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way seems to use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`** action hook, to embed your code in it and to display it in your product pages.

> But you need to be sure that the ID **`511`** is a **product category** (and not a normal WP category. If not you will be obliged to create it and to replace this ID by the name, the slug or the ID of your new product category.

This should be your code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','my_custom_product_content', 1, 0 );
function my_custom_product_content(){
    global $post, $product;

    if(has_term( array(531), 'product_cat', $post->ID )) {

        if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) { 
            ?>
            <p>
            &darr; Download Image<br />
            <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'web', true);
            echo $image_url[0]; ?>" ><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForWeb.png" alt="download for web" /></a><br />

            <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'print', true);
            echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForPrint.png" alt="download for print" /></a><br />

            <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'', true);
            echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForProPrint.png" alt="download for pro print" /></a><br />
            </p>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <h2>Special permission required</h2>
            <p>In order to use this image you need special permission from the admin, please fill in the form below and we'll get back to
            you as soon as possible...</p>
            <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form 11 "special permission"]' ) ?>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <p>
        &darr; Download Image<br />
        <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'web', true);
        echo $image_url[0]; ?>" ><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForWeb.png" alt="download for web" /></a><br />

        <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'print', true);
        echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForPrint.png" alt="download for print" /></a><br />

        <a href="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'', true);
        echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="download"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url' )?>/img/downloadForProPrint.png" alt="download for pro print" /></a><br />
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works…